# dont know why it's asking for a required character

Tags: css

so i linked a css file to an html one, but an error keeps popping and i really dont know what to do.
it says that { is required. (in the first line of code on "stylesheet"). thank you in advance

**html head and css**

```
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title >
          home 
       
        </title> 

</head>
    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
body
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps

Comment: can you post the full markup for the html head? Also the markup you have pasted here, is that from the HTML file or the attached CSS file?

Comment: edited to add the html head. the markup is from the attached css

Comment: The browser complains about a missing `{` because what you have shown, is not valid CSS. Valid CSS requires curly braces after the selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be
HTML

```
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>home</title> 
</head>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

simple beginners guide https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: tried, the other error remains and gives a new one on }, saying required selector

Comment: @greglama if it is a linked stylesheet file, you do not need the <style> tags within the file.

Comment: ok thank you. still the other error won't go away and i dont understand why